# Method info( java.util.HashMap ) not found in class'org.apache.log.Logger'

Tags: java, apache, jmeter, beanshell

```
 log.info(m.differenceValue(jsonElement1,jsonElement2));
```

calling function from beanshell. The code implemented in jar file.

```
public static <K, V> Map<String,Object> differenceValue(JsonElement json1, JsonElement json2){
    Gson g = new Gson();

    Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
    Map<String,Object> firstMap = g.fromJson(json1, mapType);
    Map<String, Object> secondMap = g.fromJson(json2, mapType);
   return(mapDifference(firstMap,secondMap));
}      
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> mapDifference(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> left, Map<? extends K, ? extends V> right) {
    Map<K, V> difference =  new HashMap<K, V>();
    difference.putAll(left);
    difference.putAll(right);
    difference.entrySet().removeAll(right.entrySet());
    return difference;
}
```

Is is working fine in eclipse but in jmeter it is throwing

> error:Method info( java.util.HashMap ) not found in class'org.apache.log.Logger'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `log.info(m.differenceValue(jsonElement1,jsonElement2).toString());`

according to documentation, that might work for HashMap (depending on what you have for the keys & values there)

> public String toString()
>
> Returns a string representation of this map.
>   The string representation consists of a list of key-value mappings in
>   the order returned by the map's entrySet view's iterator, enclosed in
>   braces ("{}"). Adjacent mappings are separated by the characters ", "
>   (comma and space). Each key-value mapping is rendered as the key
>   followed by an equals sign ("=") followed by the associated value.
>   Keys and values are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(Object).

Comment: Hi Yuri thanks for the solution shared.  It is printing data now

Comment: No prob. Accept the answer, please, if you think it solves the problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass a **Map** to [Logger](https://excalibur.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/log/Logger.html) while it accepts only Strings for [info()](https://excalibur.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/log/Logger.html#info(java.lang.String)), [warn()](https://excalibur.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/log/Logger.html#warn(java.lang.String)), etc. methods to you will need to cast the Map to String somehow.

Also I don't think you have generics support in Beanshell, consider switching to [JSR223 Elements and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) instead.